# Join parameter estimation is always better than independent parameter estimation. True?

Tags: estimation

I have the vague recollection of a result that states something along the lines of

> Joint parameter estimates always lead to smaller variance than
>   independent parameter estimates even when the
>   parameters are uncorrelated.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? What is the more accurate statement of the result, and where can I find a reference?

Comment: What does it mean for parameters to be *uncorrelated*? (I realize you're trying to jog this from memory. Is there anything more you can tell us?)

Comment: I suppose it should be taken to mean _unrelated_ to avoid the statistical connotations. The example I remember being brought up was something along the lines of estimating a parameter from a set of observations (e.g. mean shoe size), and another parameter from a complete different set of observations (e.g. mean highway fuel efficiency).

Comment: It looks like what I had in mind is [Stein's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_example). Does anyone have a simple explanation of Stein's example?

Comment: There are some good textbook treatments or, for a readable overview, you can look at B. Efron and C. Morris, [Stein's paradox in statistics](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf) *Scientific American* **236** (5): 119–127.

Comment: There are also a coupld questions on Stein's paradox on this site, but I don't think either of them answers your general question. Also, if this is, indeed, what you intended to ask about, it'd be good to update your question accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was thinking of [Stein's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_example), although it does not appear to lead a practical improvement in the estimate of a parameter.  If anyone has a nice intuitive explanation of Stein's example, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: Hrm, one really simple explanation:  When estimating multiple values, the extreme individual estimates are likely due to dumb luck and need shrunken to better match their true values.  A reasonable target to shrink towards is the average of all the individual estimates.